# ASP.NET MVC: render view to generate PDF: use iTextSharp or better solution?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I display receipt in both HTML and printer-friendly version. HTML version does jQuery tabs, etc, while printer-friendly has zero scripts and external dependencies, no master layout, no additional buttons, inline CSS, and can be saved as HTML without problems.

Since I use Spark View Engine, I though maybe it's a good idea to generate PDF using iTextSharp engine. But after few paragraphs I decided it's too cumbersome, because a) I would have to rewrite entire receipt (source Spark view is about 5 pages long) b) I had problems with iTextSharp from beginning - for example, numbered lists kept bulleted, with no indentation, and indentationLeft="20" didn't work - maybe because of lack of documentation, but see (a).

So, my requirements for PDF are very simple: I want to keep the same HTML but insert page breaks between individual receipts (yes I have several ones in a single document).

Is there a simple way to generate PDF from view/HTML without rewriting the view using a strange <s>half-documented</s> engine?

UPDATE: tried community HTMLDoc version; didn't use my inline CSS styles, incorrectly displayed Unicode symbols for currencies. [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) did pick the CSS but failed for currency symbol; <s>I suppose there's problem with encoding</s> solved by setting charset to utf-8. wkhtmltopdf seems to be nice but I'm yet to figure out how to set page breaks...

Comment: Not to mention the Java feel of the API of the clunky port iTextSharp is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used wkhtmltopdf which works fine when I set encoding, I found out how to setup page breaks, and it processes my CSS very nice. On issue is that it can't correctly process stdin/out in Windows version (don't remember if it's in or out that doesn't work) - may be fixed in recent versions, but I'm ok with temp files.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have the HTML in memory then you can convert it to PDF. I've once did something similar using [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//). It is a JAVA framework that bundles iText and that is capable of converting an HTML stream into PDF. As it is written in JAVA I've used the [ikvmc.exe](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) to convert the jar file into a .NET assembly and use it directly from managed code.

Comment: Cool for at least ikvmc link, nice stuff to know. Not sure if I want to pull all of the dependencies, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Pdf : IPdf
    {
        public FileStreamResult Make(string s)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var document = new Document())
                {
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                    document.Open();
                    using (var str = new StringReader(s))
                    {

                        var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);

                        htmlWorker.Parse(str);
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyPdfName.pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                return new FileStreamResult(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 omu - just found this whilst looking for itextsharp pdf mvc implementations. any other 'nice' pointers on this that you've found?? had thought that the additon of a stylesheet parameter might be useful in the make() method, but then I'm a nood on itexsharp, so not sure if i'm missing a trick. i presume the interface was:     public interface IPdf
    {
        FileStreamResult Make(string s);
    }