# Razor View To Word Document or PDF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I generate a Word Document or a PDF using a razor view (for determining how it is layed out) in ASP.NET MVC 3? Probably through the use of something like OpenXML SDK (for WordprocessingML) or iTextSharp (for PDF). I want to enable those that know HTML to be able to change the look of a generated Word Document or PDF without needing to write any C# code.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859683/asp-net-mvc-render-view-to-generate-pdf-use-itextsharp-or-better-solution), and ended up using http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

It generates PDF from HTML (that you can render using the usual Razor view). The result is **very** good. You may need to render you view into memory string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808348/using-razor-without-mvc).

As for doc, you can specify content type to be Microsoft Word while sending HTML inside, Word will accept and convert it. E.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342749/exporting-rendered-html-page-to-word-is-not-working-in-ie).

If you want users to change the final document, you can render you view and set contenteditable for the resulting HTML. E.g.

```
 <div contenteditable>GENERATED HTML</div>
```

Or use something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). Then, when users post back this HTML, you use it to pass to wkhtmlpdf and you get PDF.

Comment: I have done the HTML trick before with Word (which is a bit of a hack really), but would prefer it to generate a real Word Document. There is also no guarantee that it will work in the future, or with other applications (e.g. LibreOffice) that open Word Documents

Answer (score 4):

I just implemented [Rotavia](http://nuget.org/packages/Rotativa) into my project. It took about 5 minutes to get working.

Answer (score 4):

This question's a little old now, but for the sake of future visitors I've written a blog post about how to return a regular MVC view as a Word Document.

http://benjii.me/2014/01/download-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-word-document/

The core piece of this functionality comes from the WordDocumentAttribute Action Filter I created: https://gist.github.com/bjcull/8702230

Comment: Hello Ben, I followed your blog and download is working fine with html content, but its not getting the model information I am supplying to the view. Can I add the model information (like @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.FirstName)) to the downloaded page or this method only works when there is html tags in View?

Comment: I passed the viewModel I created in controller and passed with the view and its working great!. Thanks for the blog!